# Real time ray tracer

Tags: c++, windows, real-time, raytracing

I would like to make a basic real time CPU ray tracer in C++ (mainly for learning proposes). [This tutorial](http://www.codermind.com/articles/Raytracer-in-C++-Part-I-First-rays.html) was great for making a basic ray tracer. But what would be the best solution to draw this on the screen in real time? I'm not asking on how to optimize the ray tracing-part, just the painting part so that it would paint on the screen and not in a file.

I'm developing on/for windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check out [this Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1988/Guide-to-WIN32-Paint-for-beginners) on the basic paint mechanism using Win32API

Update: OP wants fast drawing, which the Win32API does not provide.  The OP needs this so that they can measure speedup of the ray-tracing algorithm during optimization process.  Other possibilities for drawing are: DirectX, XNA, Allegro, OpenGL.

Comment: Is the win32 api with paintpixel and a double buffer really the best solution?

Comment: –1 entirely inadequate, speed-wise.

Comment: So thinking about speed, what is the best solution?

Comment: _Best_ is relative: it depends on your needs.  Its advantage is that it is available on all Windows boxes.  There are other solutions as well: DirectX, Allegro, XNA -- these might be faster, but you do need special setup.  Ray tracing caclulations are usually pretty slow, so I don't think a fast drawing library will help you much

Comment: I don't want the drawing to be the bottleneck; since I wan't to play with trying to optimize the ray trace algorithm.

Comment: But OpenGL should be fast enough?

Answer (score 1):

I'm professionally working on a realtime CPU raytracer, and from what I saw with 2 years of work there, the GPU part to display image won't be the bottleneck, the bottleneck if you reach it will be the speed of your RAM, I don't think the drawing technology will make any significant difference.

As an example, we are using clustering (one CPU is not enough :p), we were able to render 100-200fps at 1920x1080 when looking the sky but the bottleneck was not the display part, it was the network...
EDIT: We are using OpenGL for the display.

When you are doing a CPU raytracer you are not gonna do printPixelToGPU() but you will write to your RAM and then send it to the GPU once the image is finished. Doing printPixelToGPU() would probably cause an big overhead and it is (in my opinion) a really bad design choice.

It looks like premature optimization. But if you are still concerned about that, just do a bench of how many RAM textures to GPU transfer you can do with OpenGL, directX..., and print the average framerate. You will probably see that the framerate will be really really high, so you will certainly never reach that "bottleneck" unless you are using SDRAM or a really poor GPU.